# Release and move child window by dragging it

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsevent

I am trying to implement an edge-docking feature between two `NSWindow`s. When the user moves the window I that can be docked just below the main window I snap it into position and add it as a child window to tha main window. This works very well.
However, I am unable to move the docked window away by simply dragging it. Currently I listen for the `NSLeftMouseDragged` event and when it starts I undock the window by removing it as child from the main window. This works, but the window is not getting moved. You have to release the mouse button and start a new dragging action to move the window away. I am guessing this happens because when the first drag is initiated the window is sat as a child window and therfore cannot be moved by that drag, even thought it gets released in the mean time.
Is there any way around this?
Thank you